# Походження виразу ЙОКЕЛЕМЕНЕ!

Tags: етимологія

Часто чую вираз **йокелемене**.У [Словнику українського сленгу](http://slovopedia.org.ua/57/53401/374624.html) знаходжу:

> **ЙОКЕЛЕМЕНЕ** 
>   вигук; мол., евфем. Вираження незадоволення, досади.

Однак, звучить цей вираз як абревіатура. Чи є якесь розшифрування цього виразу?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Йокелемене* — очевидно від російського *[ёклмн](//ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D1%91%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%BC%D0%BD)*.

*Ёклмн*, у свою чергу, є одним із серії російських виразів (поряд із *[ёлки-палки](//ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D1%91%D0%BB%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%BA%D0%B8)*, *[ё-моё](//ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D1%91-%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%91)* тощо), що є евфемізмами до російського слова:

> [ебать](//ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%B5%D0%B1%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C)

— зокрема, ймовірно, виразу:

> [ёб твою мать](//ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D1%91%D0%B1_%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%8E_%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C)

Всупереч розповсюдженій думці, ці лайливі висловлення (приховані в «цитатах» вище) не є характерними лише для російської мови, а [присутні в багатьох слов'янських мовах](/a/619), зокрема в українській:

> [їбати](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9D%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B0_%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0#%D0%87%D0%B1%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8)

Але про походження слова *йокелемене* через російську, а не безпосередньо від відповідного українського слова, свідчить те, що воно починається з *йо-*, а не з *ї-*.

Answer (score 3):

Це частина російського алфавіту:
й - ка- ле - ме - не (е, к, л, м, н)
Далі слідує:
о - пе - ре - се - те (о, п, р, с, т). 
В подальшому, ці два вислови були частково відозмінені в повсякчасному спілкуванні.

Comment: @follower, по-моєму, версії одна одній аж ніяк не суперечать: це (1) евфемізм по принципу «перша літера мату + щось», а (2) в ролі другої частини взяті послідовні літери російського алфавіту.

Comment: Так, я помилився. "Й, к, л, м, н" звісно ж. @Sasha, дякую.